# How to sort a 2-d array in java when column is specified by the user?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I was wanting to sort a 2-d array by column.  The array comes from a csv file and some columns are strings, some are integers, and some are double.  The user should be able to specify the column number.

So If I have this array

row1    [["1","cat","3.25"],
row2     ["10","dog","18.64"],
row3     ["2","aaa","15.21"]]

and the first column was sorted, the rows would be sorted 1,3,2. Not 1,2,3 as a simple string sort would return.  I know I could use the Arrays.sort method and just create my own comparator and use a try catch to determine if the string in the specified column is an integer or double but that seems a little much for something that seems so simple.

Comment: You've got your solution. It's in the question. Except you relly should make sure *all* the rows have an int in this column before sorting.

Comment: Instead of storing as rows, why not make a new class to encapsulate the data, and also parse the data into the correct type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort List of HashMaps based on hashMap values \[not keys\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420311/sort-list-of-hashmaps-based-on-hashmap-values-not-keys)

Comment: JB Nizet - I know that is one solution, I just dont particularly like it.  I was wanting to figure out if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: Do you know the types of the columns in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Think about a regular sorting algorithm for a 1-D array. Most of them either compare two elements and determine whether or not to swap them, or they go through and find the smallest element. Now, if you are sorting by column one, you do something similar. Compare two arrays by comparing their *n*-th elements, and determine whether or not to swap them. Or, go through all of the arrays and find the one with the smallest *n*-th element.